# MATLAB: Find function within range

Tags: matlab, find, range, indices

How can I use the `find` function within specific ranges.

Say, I have an array `arr1` with random values. I have the start & end indices of the portions I'd like to analyze (in this example, I want to find the first occurrence for when the value is larger than 0.8)

How could the `find` function be used here with start and end indices and the condition as well?

For example:

```
arr1 = rand(1000,1);
start_ind = [100;500;850];
end_ind = [160;620;925];

for i = 1:length(start_ind)
    output = find(arr1(start_ind(i):end_ind(i)) >=0.8); % ????
end
```

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second argument of `find` to only get the first match. You can then shift indices by adding `start_ind - 1`:

```
arr1 = rand(1000,1);
start_ind = [100; 500; 850];
end_ind = [160; 620; 925];

output = zeros(length(start_ind), 1);
for i = 1:length(start_ind)
    output(i) = find(arr1(start_ind(i):end_ind(i)) >=0.8, 1) + start_ind(i) - 1;
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help **nirvana-msu**. This works well if a value above 0.8 in this case is found. However otherwise, it will throw an "Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix" error.

Comment: Found it. Adding this second line of code will make it work if a value is not found: `output = find(boost(str_ind(i):end_ind(i)) >=165, 1) + str_ind(i) - 1;
index(i,1:length(output)) = output; ` Thank you.